# node js Buffer add NULL terminated message

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, buffer

First try with node js and Tcp sockets.

for a valid request, I need to send a message with XML to the server that needs to be terminated with null (0x00).

So far i came up with the code below to send the message, but I don't know how to add the NULL terminator.

```
const client = new net.Socket();

client.connect(port, address, () => {
 attachments.forEach((attachment) => {
    const request = setValueToXml(attachment);
    const buffer = new Buffer(request);
    client.write(buffer); // <-- What do I need to add here?
  });
});
client.on('data', (resp) => {
  console.log('You have mail', resp);
});
```

Comment: Why dont you append the null to the `buffer` ?

Comment: @Malice, I tried with buffer.write(null) but then i get `TypeError: Argument must be a string` as error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply concat buffer

```
 var bufferNull = new Buffer([0x00])
 buffer = Buffer.concat([buffer, bufferNull]);
 client.write(buffer);
```

Comment: worked like a charm, on a side note, the package smart-buffer has a way to create nul terminated messages, this also worked for me, but it would also mean i had to add a new package, the solution written by you is the shortest and at this moment the most relevant